# How to fix Startup Disk Creator which ends in an unhandled exception?

Tags: python, 17.10, python3, startup-disk-creator

I am starting the ubuntu start up disk creator (usb-creator-gtk) on Ubuntu 17.10 (4.13.0-37-generic) and getting this dialog:

[image]

I already reinstalled it by:

```
sudo apt remove usb-creator-gtk
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

And I checked its installation path:

```
whereis  usb-creator-gtk
usb-creator-gtk: /usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk /usr/share/man/man8/usb-creator-gtk.8.gz
```

And I tried to start it directly with:

```
/usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk
```

And i did a hexdump which showes there is no `0xd9` at position two. There is an `0x21`:

```
hd -n 32 /usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk
00000000  23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 70 79 74 68 6f  |#!/usr/bin/pytho|
00000010  6e 33 0a 0a 23 20 43 6f  70 79 72 69 67 68 74 20  |n3..# Copyright |
```

But still the same issue.

**How to fix Startup Disk Creator which ends in an exception?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a bug report

This looks like a bug that affects Ubuntu 17.10 in your computer. I suggest that you create a bug report at [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net/).

**Edit:** I tested in my 'testing Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 installed system', and it works to install (clone) Lubuntu 17.10.1 amd64 with the Startup Disk Creator. So I cannot report the bug. Of course, we have different hardware, but another difference could be the installation. My system was a fresh installation from the 17.10 iso file, and kept up to date. Was your system upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu?

### Use another tool

Until it is fixed, I suggest that you use another tool to create a USB boot drive,

- **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` (which comes with Ubuntu)
- [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) which is installed via a PPA

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for *live* standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```

Comment: Yep, I think I started once with Ubuntu 15, walking through all releases. Don't want to setup the system from scratch. Hopefully this 'upgrade-bug' is obsolete with the next update to 18.04.

Comment: @eDeviser, Yes, let us hope so.